# Security fixes for Rails 3.2-stable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.2

I use Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.21 in my app.

I'm going to upgrade Ruby to 2.2.0. I'm going to use [Rails 3-2-stable](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3-2-stable), because Rails 3.2.21 doesn't support this version of Ruby (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18201). Does anybody know if new security fixes will be added to this branch? If yes, how should I upgrade Rails if they will be added?

I'm going to add this line to Gemfile:

> gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "3-2-stable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [rails maintenance policy](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html) rails 3-2 receives only fixes for severe security problems (the decision on whether a vulnerability is severe or not is at the core team's discretion).

When rails 5 comes out (currently targeting autumn 2015), the 3.2 branch will become completely unsupported.

Comment: I understand that rails 3.2.x will receive security fixes, but what's about rails 3.2-stable branch?

Comment: Ok, according to link you've sent security fixes will be applied to "stable" branch, but how should I check and pull these fixes? There isn't version of gem in Gemfile.

Comment: If you knew that new fixes had been pushed you would run `bundle update rails`